# is socketChannel.register() synchronized with close() method in java NIO?

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous, nio, channel

In openJDK(jdk-6u23)this implementation of AbstractSelectableChannel.register() just like below:

it first checks whether this channel is open or not.and then do the register work with reg lock.but if we invoke the close method between the isOpen() test and synchronized block,the channel will be closed.then we will register a CLOSED channel with a selector... But is this right?

```
public final SelectionKey register(Selector sel, int ops,
                   Object att)
throws ClosedChannelException
{
if (!isOpen())
    throw new ClosedChannelException();
if ((ops & ~validOps()) != 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
synchronized (regLock) {
    if (blocking)
    throw new IllegalBlockingModeException();
    SelectionKey k = findKey(sel);
        if (k != null) {
            k.interestOps(ops);
    k.attach(att);
        }
    if (k == null) {
    // New registration
    k = ((AbstractSelector)sel).register(this, ops, att);
    addKey(k);
    }
        return k;
    }
}
```

Comment: i just do a test that the channel could be registered with the selector.but i think when we read from the channel we will get an error.

Comment: I would file a bug report on this with Oracle.